# Is this correct? An absolute value question with a picture.

Tags: absolute-value

I found this answer to this online firstly is it true and secondly please can you explain to me how so?

The question is what could the range be in this expression if x is any real number.

[image]

Comment: Thank you. I posted the link now.

Comment: What do you mean ? You can plug in literally every x here. I suspect you mean |x-3| - |x+1| is equal to something?

Comment: Like I mean how many values can the absolute value be equal to?

Comment: And what can I fill in in the x? Any real number? Or integers?

Comment: Is this function related where they ask you to find the image of this function? Then you need to specify a domain..

Comment: X can also be an integer.

Comment: And nothing else?

Comment: Sorry x can be any real number.

Comment: Then the answer is +infinity.

Comment: I'm not asking what x can be I'm asking what the range could be of this expressio . I'm sorry.

Comment: Okay finally a question that makes sense!

Comment: I'm new to maths .

Comment: After you ask a question here, if you get an acceptable answer, you should "accept" the answer by clicking the check mark ✓ next to it. This scores points for you and for the person who answered your question. You can find out more about accepting answers here: [How do I accept an answer?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/3286/), [Why should we accept answers?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/3399/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If $x>=3$ then the expression becomes $(x-3) - (x+1) = - 4$.

If $x<=-1$ then it becomes $(3-x)-(-x-1) = 4$.

If $-1<x<3$ then it is $(3-x)-(x+1)=2-2x$, which can take any value in $(-4,4)$.

So you are correct,  there are 9 possible whole number values, from -4 to 4 inclusive.

Answer (score 0):

So given the function $$f: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}: x \mapsto|x- 3| - |x+1|$$

what is the range of $f$?

We can rewrite this function in the following way:

$f(x) = \begin{cases} (x-3) - (x+1)  = -4 \quad\quad \mathrm{if}\quad\quad 3 \leq x \\(3-x) - (x+1) = 2 - 2x \quad\quad \mathrm{if}\quad\quad -1 \leq x \leq 3\\(3-x) - (-(x+1)) = 4 \quad\quad \mathrm{if}\quad\quad x \leq -1 \end{cases}$

So we can have the values $\{-4,4\}$ for $x \in \mathbb{R}-[-1,3]$
and we have the values $\{-4,-3,-2,-1,0,1,2,3,4\}$ for $x \in (-1,3)$. Hence, the range of this expression is $\{-4,-3,-2,-1,0,1,2,3,4\}$ and the final answer is $\boxed{9}$